# Apache2 log does not capture hping/ping data

Tags: apache

I am trying to put some log analyzer code that will use apache log to determine IP address of the attacker. I came across hping3 to attack DoS, ICMP attack, but if I use this command and ping apache the entries aren't recorded in the access log. Is there something that I am missing? Where does these requests go and escape logging? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that "almost arbitrary tcp/ip packages" are not considered as requests by the http server... What should it log? The opening of a socket without anything further happening? There is no request to be logged.

Comment: thanks @arkascha... it would be great if you can suggest me some tool that will send a DoS and ICMP packets to my site and I want to log these in apache...

Comment: @user3781914 I don't see how you will ever see ICMP packages in the apache log. About the DoS attack: that is nothing but a script that makes as many valid requests as possible. Just write such script! Though I don't see the point in an attempt to flood ones own server.

Comment: okay thanks, m trying to learn about the attacks and track them, so trying to flood my own server

Answer (score 0):

Apache is HTTP server and it logs only HTTP requests. The tools you've specified doesn't make HTTP requests.